# How to express this computer science problem mathematically?

Tags: computer-science, mathematical-modeling

I am writing my dissertation for a software degree and want to provide a mathematical formula for a function I have.

The code I want to describe consists of two parts. First to build a collection of values by doing a calulation:

The input to this code is three lists of factors labled High, Medium and Low. What the factors are arn't important but how many there are is. Say there may be 5 high factors 7 meduim and 4 low. The number of each catagory of factors is timesed by a weighting. Say 100 for high 50 for meduim and 10 for low.

This looks like:
Total Weight $= $(weighting of a high factor $\times$ Count of high factors) $+$ (weighting of a medium factor $\times$ Count of medium factors ) $+$ (weighting of a low factor $\times$ Count of low factors )

Each time it does that sum it adds the outcome to the collection of values.

Secondly afterwards the code selects the top 5 values from this collection and returns them

How would I describe this in a mathematical formula?

Comment: This is not clear.  By definition a "set" should have distinct elements...I think you don't mean that, right?  Fine, so let's just call it a collection, or a multiset.  More seriously, though, what does "medium" mean?  If my multiset is $ \{1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5\}$ I get that the max is $5$ and the min is $1$ but what would "medium" be?

Comment: Why don't you simply denote each term of your equation with a symbol ($\alpha,a,\delta,\omega_{\text{low}},\dots$) and use it as it is ?

Comment: Thank you for the correction on collection instead of set, I'll update the post.
So I'm returning the top 5 so in a collection of {1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5} I want {5,5,4,3,2}

Comment: How does that answer my question?  I asked what "Medium" was for that collection.

Comment: To stress:  I don't know how to compute your function for the example I gave.  I understand you take the top five terms.  Fine, that's $\{5,5,4,3,2\}$ as you say.  So, presumably the greatest value is $5$ and there are two of those.  The least value is $2$ and there is only one of those.  Are you calling *both* $4$ and $3$ "medium"?  so, if $A,B,C$ are your High, Medium, Low weights, the answer should be $2A+2B+C$?  Something else?   I think it is impossible to guess what you have in mind here.

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is not clear what you are asking.  If you can, please edit your post for clarity.  Maybe provide a few detailed examples of whatever you have in  mind.

Comment: Thank you lulu for your help. Sorry that the question was unclear. I hope this edit makes my question more clear.

Comment: No, still not clear.  If you have three finite collections, $A,B,C$, however defined,  and weights $w_A,w_B,w_C$, then of course you can always define the quantity $w_A\times \#(A)+w_B\times \#(B)+w_C\times \#(C)$.  No problem there.  But now if you you wish to add that value back to one of the collections you have to explain your rules.  Clearly.  Don't just say "Low, Medium, High" as though that was enough, it isn't.    Once again, numerical examples would be best.  Not sure why you haven't included any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let be $S = \{a_i \; | \; i \in [[0, n[[\}$ a collection (array) of $n$ elements. We define a map $f: S \to V$, which to each to each element of $S$ associates a value; with $V = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$.

We denote $argmax_5(S, f)$ the subset of $S$ (ie, $argmax_5(S, f) \in \mathcal{P}(S)$) containing the $5$ elements of $S$ which have the highest values for the function $f$.

You can then use $\#(E)$, the cardinal of a set $E$, for your "count". For example, if the high factors are the set $H$, then you can define the weight of the high factors as $w_H$ and multiply that by $\#(H)$. If you have another question, comment below.

Comment: So I do:

Let be $S = \{a_i \; | \; i \in [[0, n[[\}$ 
(To open a blank base set)

Let be V = ($w_H$ × $E_H$) + ($w_M$ × $E_M$) + ($w_L$ × $E_L$)
(To assign V as the formula for the element)

$f: S \to V$
(To define a function that maps each V to an element in the S set)

$argmax_5(S, f) \in \mathcal{P}(S)$
(To get he top 5 values in a set and reassign that to S)

So we are then left with a set S of the top 5 elements?

Comment: You're confusing different things. In what I put forward, $V$ is a set; it can't be the result of a function, but the space in which the possible results exist. You could you lowercase $v \in V$, for a choice of result. The choice of $E_H$ for the amount of elements in the set $H$ is confusing; since it is a number (preferably lowercase $e_H$, or better $\#(H)$): the capital $E$ seems to indicate it's a set. The notation $f: S \to V$ shows $S$ as the input set (S is your input 'type' in programming) and $V$ as the output set (return type). /continued

Comment: $argmax_5(S, f) \in \mathcal{P}(S)$ means that $argmax_5(S, f)$ is itself a new set (a set which you could rename $T$, for example), and that $T$ is a subset (subarray) of $S$, so $T$ is an element of $\mathcal{P}(S)$ (the powerset of $S$, the array of all possible subarrays of $S$). In programming terms, you could say that $S$ is a set of distinct keys of a generic type, $V$ is an enum with $5$ values, $f: S \to V$ is the dictionary with keys in $S$ and values in $V$; and $argmax_5(S,f)$ is the 5-list of keys of $S$ with maximal values in $V$ for $f$.